# Can I run a loop in the background of another loop? Python

Tags: python

Seen a few q's like these, nothing helped ):
Is there a way of running a loop to check if a number is more than say, 100, and if so, do something?
For example:

`while x == 1:
    #DoStuff`

and have this: running simultaneously in the background without waiting upon a user for their input?

```
if moneyLoop > 100:
    nCoins = nCoins + 1?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do this you have a few options:

- [Python's threading module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html)
- [Stackless Python](http://www.stackless.com/)
- [The Greenlet Library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/greenlet)

There are others if you google python parallelism libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Yes:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

It's hard to tell in more detail what you need your code to do from the snippets given but this should point you in the right direction.